# Macbook Pro completely hangs at start, no super user mode nothing

Tags: macos, boot, freeze, finder, osx-mountain-lion

I was moving some files from my external hard drive to a network drive, when the finder started crashing and starting repeatedly, so I forced it off.

After that OS X wouldn't start anymore.

I booted from the rescue partition that comes with Mountain Lion (10.8.2 I think), repaired permissions, it hung again and I forced a restart.

Again booted and repaired the hard drive itself, no errors found, tried repairing permissions again, found issues, but hung for many hours. So I had to force restart again...

Now the only thing I can get it to do is a pram/nvram reset. No start from cd, no verbose mode, no super user mode... the boot menu doesn't show up anything.

just the whitish/gray screen... (of death)

Thanks a lot in advance.

Anyone have any ideas what I can do... some secret magic I don't know of?

Edit:

I just called Apple Support, they are clueless and have never seen this before. I am planning on driving into Boston this coming week and giving it to those guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After finding this article: http://tearsinderain.wordpress.com/2011/12/18/white-screen-death/

I was on the right track I was able to start the computer again from a external recovery hard drive I had around. I tested the hard drive and it was completely broken. So all I had to do
is get a new drive from the closest store and take out the old one and replace it.

Time Machine Backup restored and all was good.